# Name object with Variable Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    timesheets.i =  { name, day, month, date, year, time };
}
```

When I run this code, it just overwrites the values for timesheets as it loops.

How can I name the different objects within timesheets using the variable `i`?

edit:

The first comment helped a ton. But when I try and create different object using

```
timesheets[name] = { name, day, month, date, year, time };
```

it overwrites the values instead of adding an additional object. When I try and use

```
timesheets[name] += { name, day, month, date, year, time };
```

It console logs as

```
{
  'Pres Trump': 'undefined[object Object][object Object]',
  'Pres Obama': 'undefined[object Object][object Object]'
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

edit:

fixed with

```
if(timesheets[name] == undefined){
                timesheets[name] = [ dateOutput, time ]
            }else{
                timesheets[name] +=  [ dateOutput, time ];
            }
```

Comment: `timesheets[i]`

Comment: It would probably make more sense to use an array instead of a generic object here anyway.

Comment: The end goal is to end up with an object that resembles

timesheets: Username: {timesheet information}{timesheet information}{timesheet information}
secondUsername:  {timesheet information}{timesheet information}{timesheet information}

So on and so forth